# JQuery Datatable Colvis is not showing in codepen code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I given my code in codepen for your views and I am unable to fix why Colvis is not showing in the output.

```
[https://codepen.io/Sixthsense6/pen/poKZoVz][1]
```

Don't know why SO is pushing me to embed the link under code tag.

[image: Colvis]

Comment: not clear on what the issue is?

Comment: As it states: *Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code.* - if the 3rd-party site goes down, your question is nothing.  Include the code in the question (unless it's too long, then include the minimum code here with a link to the full code).  See [mcve]

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?  Always check the console for errors.

Comment: You're missing a `"` on your script tag - add this and it works fine.   I copied your code to jsfiddle and it showed immediately in the syntax formatter.  (it also shows in codepen, but it's not as obvious to me)

Comment: @ freedomn-m, Yeah you fixed it :)  Please post your suggestion as answer I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes in the second script, at the end of the url. You don't need to add scripts in settings as pointed out by @freedomn-m

**Other option -**

You can add your scripts in JS tab **"Add External Scripts/Pens
"** and styles in css tab

Attached the screenshot

Check this link `**https://codepen.io/nishant1207/pen/ExRpaBe?editors=1111**`. It works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Not if they're in `<script>` tags